# How to get attribute_id from “eav_attribute” table in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, sql, query

I need to get attribute_id from `eav_attribute` table, I have `attribute_code` and `frontend_label`, my sql query will be some thing like this.

```
select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'sb_store_id'
```

What will be its equivalent magento statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get id from attribute code like that

```
$attribute_code = "sb_store_id"; 
$attribute_details =
Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute('catalog_product',    $attribute_code);

echo $attribute_details->getAttributeId(); //marius suggestion
```

Comment: you can just call `$attribute_details->getAttributeId()` instead of calling `getData` first.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you should do it.

You need to know the entity type to be able to get it (product,category...).

Example for product:

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY , 'sb_store_id');
```